# Compiler adds random `1 to my interface instances

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a `RestClient` of type `IRestClient` that does a request and gets a response.

the response is of type `IRestResponse`.

In the Unit test using Nunit I do:

```
var response = new RestResponse<MyResponse>
{
    Content = "some string"
};

this.mockRestClient.Setup(c => c.ExecuteTaskAsync(It.IsAny<RestRequest>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(response);
```

In the code this happens:

```
var response =
            (await this.client
                .ExecuteTaskAsync(request))
                .EnsureStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
return response.ParseContent<MyResponse>().Data;
```

`ParseContent` method does this:

```
public static IRestResponse<T> ParseContent<T>(this IRestResponse response)
{
     if (!(response is RestResponse fullResponse))
     {
          throw new NotSupportedException($"Currently requires a concrete {typeof(RestResponse).Name}");
     }
 }
```

The API works correctly in various environments but the Nunit integration test fails with the error

> Currently requires a concrete `RestResponse`

When I debug it, it is of type `` RestResponse`1 ``

As you can appreciate this is very hard problem to search both in Google but also here in Stackoverflow because no search engine considers the backtick.

Does anyone know what this is and how to make Nunit behave correctly?
Type checking becomes a nightmare if instances are of `` T`1 `` type instead of `T`

Why does Nunit test project generate a new type while the actual application doesn't?

Comment: The backtick is the "arity" marker - it denotes "a generic object with one type argument". You see it in stacktraces etc.  - _"Backtick "`" plus integer specifies the arity of the Generic type, and is actually burned in at the metadata level as the string type name. GetType() takes an unmangled string name and simply brings it to life by string comparing over the metadata table. It's unfortunate that we couldn't use angle brackets to specify arity, ala C# syntax, but the C++ folk have already reserved them in the type name grammar."_

Comment: That's not a new type that indicates that it's generic and has one generic type.  The issue seems to be that you compare it to a non-generic type of the same name.

Comment: why does the "is" check fail and why does it fail only when running Nunit and not anytime else?

Comment: `'1` is what gets printed when you show a generic type with one parameter. Try this: `Console.WriteLine(typeof(Nullable<int>))` It would print `System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]`.

Comment: excellent, you guys have answered what the backtick is but not why the code is throwing an exception (only in the test) and how to fix it

Comment: What's the definition of `RestResponse` and `RestResponse<T>`? It looks like `RestResponse<T>` does not extend `RestResponse` and only implements `IRestResponse`. It looks like you should change the argument type in `ParseContent<T>` to be `RestResponse` instead of dynamically checking the type.

Answer (score 2):

`RestResponse<MyResponse>` does implement `IRestResponse`, but it does not extend `RestResponse`.

In C#, generic types and their non-generic equivalents are not actually the same class. A response that doesn't have a specific type of data with it is represented in this framework as a `RestResponse`, whereas responses with a data type are represented as `RestResponse<T>` (which is represented by a back-tick when ToString()'d.

I'm not entirely clear on the intent of your `ParseContent<>` method, or how the code works outside of unit tests, but you may want to try creating your test data like this:

```
var response = new RestResponse
{
    Content = "some string"
};
```

That way, you're providing the "concrete RestResponse" type that the method is asking for. And I assume the method itself produces a `RestResponse<MyResponse>` based on the contents of the `RestResponse` you pass in.

Comment: response.ParseContent<MyResponse>() doesn't throw this error.

response if of type IRestResponse and MyResponse does NOT implement RestResponse

Comment: @Nick I didn't say MyResponse implements RestResponse. I said `RestResponse<MyResponse>` (or, if you prefer, `RestResponse<T>`) implements `IRestResponse`.

Comment: But your test says that `MyResponse` has to be a `RestResponse`.